# how to replace URI to input Stream, access images in order when updating function

Tags: java, eclipse, java-io

```
public static BufferedImage[] GetAllLevels() {

    URL url = LoadSave.class.getResource("/lvls");
    File file = null;

    try {
        file = new File(url.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    File[] filesSorted = new File[files.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < filesSorted.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
            if (files[j].getName().equals((i + 1) + ".png"))
                filesSorted[i] = files[j];

        }

    BufferedImage[] imgs = new BufferedImage[filesSorted.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
        try {
            imgs[i] = ImageIO.read(filesSorted[i]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return imgs;
}
```

I'm beginning, so I taken that code from somewhere but couldn't find alternative method

Here are some errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect. InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImp1.invoke®(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImp1. invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImp1. java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect .DelegatingMethodAccessorImp1.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImp1. java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method. invoke (Method. java: 568)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader. JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java: 61)

    > Caused by: java. lang. IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    > at java.base/java.io.File.‹init›(File. java: 420)
    > at utilz. LoadSave.GetAllLevels (LoadSave. java:77)
    > at levels.LevelManager.buildAllLevels(LevelManager.java:41)
    > at levels. LevelManager.<init›(LevelManager.java:23) at gamestates.Playing.initClasses (Playing. java: 130) 
    > at gamestates.Playing.<init>(Playing.java:64) 
    > at main.Game.initClasses(Game. java: 54) at main. Game.<init> (Game. java: 40) 
    > at main.MainClass.main(Mainclass.lava:6)
```

Comment: Please include the error message as *text* in the question. (I'd also strongly advise you to research Java naming conventions, and start following them.) Now, what's the value of `url.ToURI()`? That looks like it's the problem here... note that you shouldn't assume that every resource *is* a file in the file system... if your data is in a jar file for example, `File.listFiles` isn't going to help you.

Comment: You can't access resources *as* directories. If you want to access several images in a serial fashion like that, you will need to come up with a naming scheme *per file* to access them sequentially

Comment: Sidenote: Catching checked exceptions and doing `e.printStackTrace()` is a bad practice which leads you to a really convoluted code (as seen here) and even worse, might lead you to `NullPointerException`s which are hard to trace. If you don't know what to do with those exceptions then it would be better to just declare them in the throws statement in your method signature or surround the whole code with try catch which will convert them to a wrapped `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Okay I will try

Answer (score 0):

```
    final int MAX_IMAGES = 10;
    for(int i = 0;i < MAX_IMAGES;i++) {  
        String fileName = String.format("%02d.png", i);
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/" + fileName);
        if (in == null) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            // Process
        }
    }
```

could be considered as a strategy

Comment: So i have a program that set level and and i have images with 1.png… to 5.png, so i could add format(i +”.png”)

Comment: If you've only got such a low number then you don't need to format at all.